# Conditional Jumps not Working as Intended in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to write a program that does the following:

1. Store an integer in the `bx` register
2. If the value stored in the `bx` register is less than or equal to 4, copy `A` into the `al` register
3. If the value stored in the `bx` register is greater than 10, copy `B` into the `al` register
4. If none of these two conditions are true, copy `C` into the `al` register
5. Output the value of the `al` register

This is the program I wrote:

```
section .data

section .text
    global _start
    
    _start:
        mov bx, 2
        
        cmp bx, 4
        jle copy_a
        cmp bx, 10
        jg copy_b
        mov al, 'C'
        
        copy_a:
            mov al, 'A'
            
        copy_b:
            mov al, 'B'
            
        mov byte [esp], al   ;push al
        mov eax, 0x04
        mov ebx, 0x01
        mov ecx, esp         ;esp points to the character to be printed
        mov edx, 0x01
        int 0x80
            
        mov eax, 0x01
        mov ebx, 0x00
        int 0x80
```

No matter what I change the value of `bx` to, it always outputs `B`

Comment: `mov byte [esp], al` doesn't push, it just overwrites what was in that stack memory.  That's fine, but your comments don't match the code.  If you wanted to push, you'd `push eax` (AL is the low byte of EAX, and x86 is little-endian, so ESP would be pointing to the byte from AL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a jump:

```
section .text
    global _start
    
    _start:
        mov bx, 2
        
        cmp bx, 4
        jle copy_a
        cmp bx, 10
        jg copy_b
        mov al, 'C'
        
        copy_a:
            mov al, 'A'
            jmp continue
        copy_b:
            mov al, 'B'

        continue:     
            mov byte [esp], al   ;push al
            mov eax, 0x04
            mov ebx, 0x01
            mov ecx, esp         ;esp points to the character to be printed
            mov edx, 0x01
            int 0x80    
            mov eax, 0x01
            mov ebx, 0x00
            int 0x80
```

You have to add this jump, otherwise, the processor will simply see:

```
mov al, 'A'
mov al, 'B'
```

The processor will first move `'A'` into `al`, then `'B''`. This results in `al` always being `B`.

Furthermore you forgot to add the move, if none of the conditions is true. (`bx > 4 && bx <= 10`)
Edit:
To add the third condition, try this:

```
section .text
    global _start
    
    _start:
        mov bx, 2
        
        cmp bx, 4
        jle copy_a
        cmp bx, 10
        jg copy_b
        mov al, 'C'
        jmp continue ;Here.
        copy_a:
            mov al, 'A'
            jmp continue
        copy_b:
            mov al, 'B'

        continue:     
            mov byte [esp], al   ;push al
            mov eax, 0x04
            mov ebx, 0x01
            mov ecx, esp         ;esp points to the character to be printed
            mov edx, 0x01
            int 0x80    
            mov eax, 0x01
            mov ebx, 0x00
            int 0x80
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I ran the code you provided and it seems like you were right, "C" never gets stored in "al", even though I wrote "mov al, 'C'" after the two jumps. How can I fix it?